# How to get URL of Images from that are stored in Firebase Storage in specific folder | Androi | Java

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I uploaded some pictures **manually** in firebase storage in the specific folder I want to get the URL of all images that are stored in that specific folder.
Is there any way I can get the URL of all images?

**Note**: There are many folders in my firebase storage I just wanted to get images from Driver1 as the screenshot is attached you can clearly see the images I uploaded.

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is function how to get url when uplod

```js
 reader.onload = (e) => {
                if (file == null) return;
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Your uploaded picture',
                    imageUrl: e.target.result,
                    imageAlt: 'The uploaded picture'
                })
                const imageRef = ref(storage, `user/profile/${file.nama + user.uid}`);
                uploadBytes(imageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
                    getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                        setImageUrls(url);
                    });
                });
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is certainly unclear. Please edit the answer and provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply click on the image you want to download and on the right-hand side of the page, a new section will appear, which contains the name of the image. If you click on the name, a new tab in your browser will be opened containing that particular image. You can copy the URL right from there or, at the bottom of this new section, you'll see the "File location". If you click on it, you'll see the "Access token" and if you click again on it, the download URL and the corresponding token will be copied. Then you can paste that into your web browser and you'll see the image.

[image]

**Edit:**

To be able to read or download an image from a Cloud Storage URL, please check the official documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Since you're using Android, I also recommend you a library called [Glide for Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: Hey Alex Thanks for Answering my question, I know this way but I want to get these images using coding through Android, My android project is already connected to firebase

Comment: Then have you tried using the code that exist in the official documentation? If yes, show us what you have tried and doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: I didn't found code for this related to my project

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Hey Jawad. Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other information?